# ds1820 address, pointers, and I2C

Tags: pointers, arduino, i2c

I'm running into a number of issues attempting to get code for a 328p arduino to compile. The idea here is using a request handler to take commands on an I2C bus from a master and send the master temps from a DS1820 temperature probe or a hall effect sensor flow meter.  Firstly, I've tried to use pointers and I'm not sure if I'm anywhere near the mark on their implementation, or if there is any advantage to doing so here. Second, The DeviceAddress format is giving me some trouble, and I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong there. The code is a bit messy, but I've done a lot of commenting, including questions/issues the compiler has brought up. I realize that the functions printSensorAtemp and printSensorBtemp differ significantly, and the intention in including both is to get an idea of which direction I should take.

```c++
#include <OneWire.h>    //for temperature probes
#include <Wire.h>       //for I2C
#include <DallasTemperature.h>   //also needed for temperature probes
//#include <I2C_Anything.h>      //aids in sending floats over I2C

// Data wire of temperature probes is plugged into pin 3 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 3

// data wire from flowmeter is plugged into pin 4 on the Arduino
#define hallSensor 4 

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DeviceAddress SensorA = { 0x28, 0x94, 0xE2, 0xDF, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFE };
DeviceAddress SensorB = { 0x28, 0x6B, 0xDF, 0xDF, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0 };  
char val = ' ';
int Calc;    //this is the placeholder for the calculated flow to be sent via I2C, is it an int? seedstudio has it as being DEC...
volatile float tempToPrint;

int NbTopsFan;
float Calc;
int CMD;

void setup()
{
    Wire.begin(2);                // join i2c bus with address #2 (slave)
    pinMode(hallSensor, INPUT); // sets the pinMode for the variable hallSensor, set above,      to pin 4
    pinMode(ONE_WIRE_BUS, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //attachInterrupt(0, rpm, RISING); // double check this -- where is the interrupt coming  from? what format is RPM?

    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); //declares that when I2C sends an onRequest, the function
                                  //requestEvent() gets called
    Wire.read(receiveEvent); // declares that when I2C sends a command, the variable 
                             //CMD gets updated by this function

    // Start up the one Wire sensorlibrary
    sensors.begin();
    // set the resolution to 10 bit (good enough?)
    sensors.setResolution(SensorA, 10);
    sensors.setResolution(SensorB, 10);
}

void receiveEvent(int HowMany)
{
   if(Wire.available() > 0)
   {
          CMD = Wire.read();
   }
}

void requestEvent()
{
  switch(CMD)
  {
      case 0x01: printSensorATemp(); break; // need to set bytes and types within (),     
                                            // otherwise compiler indicates too few arguments.
                                            // At 4 bytes for a float, would that cover a 
                                            // string too? Not sure how to make this agree with 
                                            // the different data types in this function.
      case 0x02: printHSensorBTemp(); break;
      case 0x03: printFlow(); break; 
      default: break; // do nothing
  }
}

void loop()
{}

void printFlow()
{
  NbTopsFan = 0;   //Set NbTops to 0 ready for calculations
  sei();      //Enables interrupts 
  delay (1000);   //Wait 1 second
  cli();      //Disable interrupts
  Calc = (NbTopsFan * 60 / 7.5); //(Pulse frequency x 60) / 7.5Q, = flow rate
  //in L/hour 
 Wire.write(Calc)
}

void printSensorATemp(DeviceAddress SensorA)
{
  float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
  if (tempC == -127.00) 
  {
    send("Error getting SensorA temp");
  } 
  else
  {
    send("SensorA Temp");
    *tempToPrint = DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC);
    if (*howMany >= (sizeof *tempToPrint)
    {
        I2C_writeAnything([glow]*[/glow]tempToPrint);
    }
}

void printSensorBTemp(DeviceAddress hotLiquorTank)
{
  float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
  if (tempC == -127.00) 
  {
    send("Error getting SensorB temperature");
  } 
  else {
    send("SensorB temp");
    send(DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC));
  }

}

}

}
```

And here's the I2C_anything, set up in another tab in the IDE.

```c++
//#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

template <typename T> int I2C_writeAnything (const T& value)
  {
    const byte * p = (const byte*) &value;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof value; i++)
          Wire.write(*p++);
    return i;
  }  // end of I2C_writeAnything

template <typename T> int I2C_readAnything(T& value)
  {
    byte * p = (byte*) &value;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof value; i++)
          *p++ = Wire.read();
    return i;
  }  // end of I2C_readAnything

template <typename T> int I2C_singleWriteAnything (const T& value)
  {
  int size = sizeof value;
  byte vals[size];
  const byte* p = (const byte*) &value;
  unsigned int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof value; i++) {
    vals[i] = *p++;
  }

//  {
  //Wire.write(vals, size);
  //return i;
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of some simply syntax stuff:

1. If I haven't miscounted then you have a couple of `}` too many at the end of your main file.
2. You are missing a ';' after `Wire.write(Calc)` in `printFlow`.
3. In your `I2C_anything.h` the `I2C_singleWriteAnything` has a `}` missing at the end.

Now some bugs:

1. `NbTopsFan` is a global variable but is only ever used in `printFlow`. Furthermore it's always set to 0 which means that the result of this calculation `(NbTopsFan * 60 / 7.5)` will also always be 0. You have to ask yourself: Where is `NbTopsFan` supposed to come from and how should it get set?
2. `Calc` is also a global variable for no apparent reason - it's only ever used in `printFlow` so it should be a local variable in that function.
3. Your comment asks for what type `Calc` is - well, it's computed by `(NbTopsFan * 60 / 7.5)` and `7.5` is a `double` so the result should be a `double`. That being said a `double` might not exist in the context of the arduino platform and the compiler might turn it into a float (meaning the compiler would not be standard conform but then a lot of embedded platform compilers aren't). I don't know the compiler or the platform so this is a bit speculation. You should be able to write `(NbTopsFan * 60 / 7.5f)` in which case the result should definitely be a `float`. In summary you can remove the global variable `Calc` and write `printFlow()` as:

   ```
   void printFlow()
   {
       NbTopsFan = 0;   //Set NbTops to 0 ready for calculations
       sei();      //Enables interrupts 
       delay (1000);   //Wait 1 second
       cli();      //Disable interrupts
       int flowRate = (NbTopsFan * 60 / 7.5); // (Pulse frequency x 60) / 7.5Q, = flow rate in L/hour 
       Wire.write(flowRate);
   }
   ```

   You still have to figure out the mystery of the `NbTopsFan`
4. In `printSensorATemp` you write `sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress)` but `deviceAddress` is not an existing variable anywhere. Did you mean to write `sensors.getTempC(SensorA)`?
5. Same in `printSensorBTemp` you probably meant to write `sensors.getTempC(hotLiquorTank)`.
6. In `printSensorATemp` you write `*tempToPrint = DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC);` which means "Dereference `tempToPrint` and store the returned value at the location it points to." Howver `tempToPrint` is not a pointer - it's a float which you cannot dereference. You could just write it as:

   ```
   var tempF = DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC);
   I2C_writeAnything(&tempF);
   ```

   Also if you convert it to Fahrenheit then why not call `sensors.getTempF()` in the first place?

This should get you at least compiling.

Comment: Chris, you're awesome. There are some really good answers here that show me a great deal about what I've been doing wrong here and give me a better idea of how to proceed. Much of what I've put together is from example code, and while it is upsetting at the lack of documentation/comments irt variables within that code, it's pretty cool I can throw some poorly written code out there, learn a bit and hopefully others will too.  I'll implement those changes and report back.